# Proof for a rank-one Decomposition theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the following result which I recently came across in a research paper in my area (Signal Processing)

> Let $X$ be a $N\times N$ positive semidefinite (psd) matrix whose rank
>   is $r$. Let $A$ be any symmetric $N\times N$ matrix. Then, there exist
>   a set of vectors $x_1,\dots,x_r$ such that \begin{align} X & =
>  \sum_{i=1}^{r}x_ix_i^T \\ x_i^TAx_i &=
>  \frac{\mbox{trace}\{AX\}}{r},~~~\forall i \end{align}

The following is the proof for it which I can't verify.

**Proof:**
Consider the following step-wise procedure whose inputs are $X$ and $A$.

$~~$0.$~~$ Inputs are $X$ (given $X\geq 0$, $rank(X)=r$) and $A$ (symmetric).

1. Decompose $X=RR^T$.
2. Generate the eigen decomposition $R^TAR=U\Lambda U^T$.
3. Let $h$ be any $N\times 1$ vector such that $\lvert h_i\rvert=1$ (each entry of $h$). Generate the vector $x_1$ and matrix $X_1$ as 
   \begin{align}
   x_1&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}RUh \\
   X_1&=X-x_1x_1^T 
   \end{align}
4. Outputs are $X_1$ and $x_1$.

The paper then claims that

- $X_1$ is psd and has rank $r-1$
- $x_1^TAx_1=\frac{1}{r}trace(AX)$

**While I am able to verify the second claim, am not able to verify the first one? How is it true?** If this can be done, the rest of the proof is straight forward. I am looking for a rigorous proof.

Read this if you are interested to know where this proof heads. Now do the stepwise algorithm earlier with inputs $X_1$ and $A$ to get $x_2$ and $X_2$ such that \begin{align}X_2&=X_1-x_2x_2^T\\&=X-x_1x_1^T-x_2x_2^T\end{align} and $$x_2^TAx_2=\frac{1}{r-1}trace(AX_1)=\frac{1}{r}trace(AX)$$ Then the result of the paper is that you can do this procedure $r$ times and get a rank-one decomposition $$X=\sum_{i=1}^{r}x_ix_i^T$$ with the property $$x_i^TAx_i\,=\,\frac{1}{r}trace(AX),~\forall i$$for any given psd X with rank $r$ and any symmetrix $A$.

Answer (score 3):

From the famous inequality ${\sf rank}(f+g)\leq {\sf rank}(f)+{\sf rank}(g)$
and from ${\sf rank}(x_1x_1^T)=1$, we deduce 
${\sf rank}(X-x_1x_1^T) \geq {\sf rank}(X)-1$. On the other hand, 
${\sf rank}(X-x_1x_1^T)$ can be equal to ${\sf rank}(X)$ under the conditions
you gave (you probably forgot some additional constraints). Consider
the following example :

$$
X=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 10 & 6 & 0 \\ 6 & 5 & 0  \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right),
A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 0 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & -2  \\ 3 & -2 & 0 \end{array}\right) \tag{1}
$$

In step $1$, I can write $X=RR^T$ where

$$
R=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 0 & 3 \\ 0 & 1 & 2  \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right) \tag{2}
$$

It happens then that $RAR^T={\sf diag}(18,-8,0)$ and $R^TAR=0$ are already diagonal, so that in step 2 we may take $U=I_3$. In step 3, if we take all the entries of $h$ equal to $1$,

$$
x_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{c} 4 \\ 3  \\ 0 \end{array}\right),
x_1x_1^{T}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 8 & 6 & 0 \\ 6 & \frac{9}{2} & 0  \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right),
X-x_1x_1^{T}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0  \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right) \tag{3}
$$

so that ${\sf rank}(X-x_1x_1^T)=2={\sf rank}(X)$.

Comment: Hi, the algo takes eigen decomposition of $R_1^TAR_1$ and not that of $R_1AR_1^T$ which is what you have considered. If you take $R_1^TAR_1$, the conclusions follow easily.

Comment: @dineshdileep It does not change much if you use $R^TAR$ instead of $RAR^T$. I have just edited my answer to make my counterexample fit both $R^TAR$ and $RAR^T$.

Comment: oh I see!!. does this happen because $trace(AX)=0$? I mean, if you consider the space of hermitian matrices, they are sort of orthogonal to each other.